# How to get EDID with Nvidia from command line

Tags: command-line, nvidia, graphics, hdmi

On a PC with an Intel GPU, I can access raw display EDID with the command line

`cat /sys/devices/pci*/0000:*/drm/card*/card*/edid`

On PC with an nvidia driver installed, the same command gives no result.
I can access the EDID by opening `nvidia-settings` and select my display and click `Acquire EDID`, then the Binary EDID file can be saved.

How to do the same from command line ?

Comment: It's seems related to this bug [992350](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/992350)

Comment: There is a way to get the EDID on nvidia with ```xrandr --verbose``` but the command output need to be parsed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use X, you can run this in command line:

```
LC_ALL=C xrandr --prop | awk '
    function print_hex_edid() {
        getline
        while (/^[[:blank:]]*[[:xdigit:]]+$/) {
            sub(/[[:blank:]]*/, "")
            printf "%s", $0
            getline
        }
        print ""
    }
    /^[[:blank:]]*EDID.*:/ {
        print_hex_edid()
    }' | xxd -r -p
```

The `xxd` command is just for converting from hex to binary, but if you use `edid-decode` to convert EDID to human readable form, you do not have to use it.